# Emacs lisp, How `interactive' reads buffer?

Tags: emacs, elisp

For example there is a function:

```
(defun testb (buf)
  (interactive "bTest: ")
  buf)
```

The question is how emacs internally reads a buffer for such interactive form?

Looks like it doesn't use `read-buffer`(or it calls the `read-buffer` as a C function(and doesn't look at symbol-function)?).

```
(flet ((read-buffer (&rest args) (current-buffer)))
  (call-interactively #'testb))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It uses Lisp function `read-buffer`. The `interactive` spec you show is equivalent to this one:

```
(interactive (list (read-buffer "Test: " nil t)))
```

See the Elisp manual, node [Using Interactive](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Using-Interactive.html).

I guess you're referring to the fact that you got this error, or similar, which you get when you try to use `flet` on a built-in function. And yes, `read-buffer` is a subr, i.e., implemented in C. `(symbol-function 'read-buffer)` returns the built-in function `#<subr read-buffer>`.

```
 Use ‘labels’, not ‘flet’, to rebind macro names
```

Comment: > _I guess you're referring to the fact that you got this error_ <   Hmm... What error? I refer to the fact that rebinding the `symbol-function` of `read-buffer` have no effect on calling a function with interactive form that reads buffer.

Comment: When I evaluate the `flet` sexp you wrote using Emacs 25.2 (after loading library `cl.el`), I get that error, saying that you cannot use `flet` on a subr.

Comment: Ah, OK.) What about `labels` and `letf`? (strange, but I don't see any error messages. How did you evaluate the code?)

Comment: I used Emacs 25.2, put the code in `*scratch*`, loaded `cl.el`, and evaluated the code using `C-x C-e`. (The error msg says to use `labels`. But `read-buffer` is not really a macro.)